# Pythonic way to pass dictionary as argument with specific keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, dictionary, parameter-passing

**What am I trying to solve:**
I want to create an object that is based on a dictionary.
The object should contain some additional methods that are out of the scope of this question.
There dictionary passed **must** contain a known set of keys.

What obviously will work is:

```
   class DictBasedObject(object):
      def __init__(self, dictionary: {})
         if 'known_key_1' in dictionary:
            self.known_key_1 = dictionary['known_key_1']
         if 'known_key_2' in dictionary:
            self.known_key_2 = dictionary['known_key_2']
         ...
```

however this way is rather cumbersome.

**How I am trying to solve:**
I would like to pass the dictionary as argument to a method, but with possibly specifying of the dictionary key-names/value-types, like:

```
   class DictBasedObject(object):
      def __init__(self, dictionary: {'known_key_1': str,
                                      'known_key_2': int,
                                      ...})
         self.known_key_1 = dictionary['known_key_1']
         self.known_key_2 = dictionary['known_key_2']
         ...
```

Obviously not much better, but at least one step towards 'more elegant'.

Is there an elegant and pythonic manner to solve this?

Comment: If the dictionary must contain a known set of keys, why do you need to check they exist, i.e. can't you can get rid of the `if` statements in your first example?

Comment: I think I formulated the question not precisely enough.
When saying _the dictionary must contain a known set of keys_ I meant something like a method's list of required arguments.
Therefore - in case any of those keys are missing - the __init__ method should fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `setattr` function:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    setattr(self, k) = v
```

or simply update the `__dict__` attribute of the object:

```
self.__dict__.update(dictionary)
```

Comment: this does solve the problem of setting the object variables.
Is there also a way of verifying that the dictionary has a given set of keys when it is being passed as argument?

Comment: You can use set difference for such a check: `if set('known_key_1', 'known_key_2') - dictionary.keys(): print('missing keys')`